# rabbitmq is it possible to prevent buggy client to create too many temp queues?

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

If the client configures to create temp queue for receiving message, is it possible to configure only one queue is allowed to create?
If buggy client creates too many queue on the server, will it be a big problem to server?

How to configure to prevent client waste resource?

```
-module(amqp_example).

-include("amqp_client.hrl").

-compile([export_all]).

test() ->
    %% Start a network connection
    {ok, Connection} = amqp_connection:start(#amqp_params_network{}),
    %% Open a channel on the connection
    {ok, Channel} = amqp_connection:open_channel(Connection),

    %% Declare a queue
    #'queue.declare_ok'{queue = Q}
        = amqp_channel:call(Channel, #'queue.declare'{}),
    ok = create_temp_queue(Channel,10),

    %% Publish a message
    Payload = <<"foobar">>,
    Publish = #'basic.publish'{exchange = <<>>, routing_key = Q},
    amqp_channel:cast(Channel, Publish, #amqp_msg{payload = Payload}),

    %% Get the message back from the queue
    Get = #'basic.get'{queue = Q},
    {#'basic.get_ok'{delivery_tag = Tag}, _Content}
        = amqp_channel:call(Channel, Get),

    %% Do something with the message payload
    %% (some work here)

    %% Ack the message
    amqp_channel:cast(Channel, #'basic.ack'{delivery_tag = Tag}),

    %% Close the channel
    amqp_channel:close(Channel),
    %% Close the connection
    amqp_connection:close(Connection),

    ok.

create_temp_queue(Channel,Loop)->
    [     %% Declare a queue
          #'queue.declare_ok'{queue = _Q}
          = amqp_channel:call(Channel, #'queue.declare'{})
          ||
        _X <- lists:seq(1,Loop)].


(emacs@yus-iMac.local)58> amqp_example:test().
** exception error: no match of right hand side value 
                    [{'queue.declare_ok',
                         <<"amq.gen-AqAaMLydgMf43y_XoYSdq5">>,0,0},
                     {'queue.declare_ok',
                         <<"amq.gen-A75g--nsvheNbwYMr34M-E">>,0,0},
                     {'queue.declare_ok',
                         <<"amq.gen-wmkOrALHBIj6Ot6ZuZZOQJ">>,0,0},
                     {'queue.declare_ok',
                         <<"amq.gen-wX2NmwMHBeDaKLvoZgJhEh">>,0,0},
                     {'queue.declare_ok',
                         <<"amq.gen-gcvScDp-RFMVwxWpyWjI-9">>,0,0},
                     {'queue.declare_ok',
                         <<"amq.gen-Q4CS7jNu3cde0RNdVdO3PJ">>,0,0},
                     {'queue.declare_ok',
                         <<"amq.gen-QKNrG8IJPVvfAlLukq38x_">>,0,0},
                     {'queue.declare_ok',
                         <<"amq.gen-wqJ2V1HQDaJjOzRDhv8gT4">>,0,0},
                     {'queue.declare_ok',
                         <<"amq.gen-AYeZiuNYsFOUMVw6xKcZh4">>,0,0},
                     {'queue.declare_ok',
                         <<"amq.gen-AJDqT2h2fq9cZOsVbNESi0">>,0,0}]
     in function  amqp_example:test/0 (src/amqp_example.erl, line 16)


yus-iMac:~ yuchen$ sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues
Password:
Listing queues ...
amq.gen-Q4CS7jNu3cde0RNdVdO3PJ  0
amq.gen-QKNrG8IJPVvfAlLukq38x_  0
amq.gen-AqAaMLydgMf43y_XoYSdq5  0
amq.gen-AJDqT2h2fq9cZOsVbNESi0  0
amq.gen-wqJ2V1HQDaJjOzRDhv8gT4  0
amq.gen-AYeZiuNYsFOUMVw6xKcZh4  0
amq.gen-wzvWzxXo2MJVZsyrwfzM8A  0
amq.gen-A75g--nsvheNbwYMr34M-E  0
amq.gen-gcvScDp-RFMVwxWpyWjI-9  0
amq.gen-wX2NmwMHBeDaKLvoZgJhEh  0
 amq.gen-wmkOrALHBIj6Ot6ZuZZOQJ 0
 ...done.
```

Comment: it depends on what you are doing. Why would you write code that lets your client just create objects like that ? It is possible to check whether an exchange exist, even to check whether a queue exists , even to check whether a queue is bound to an exchange ! you can even create a durable queue bound to a specified exchange.

Answer (score 0):

The client should create 1 queue with a specific name and make sure it is set to autodelete.  That way the client will not recreate a pre existing queue.  And each client will create its own specific queue, as each client will name its queue accordingly.

Comment: I mean bug client. It won't do accordingly. So it need to be restricted.

Comment: I dont understand, what do you mean by a bug client?

Comment: I have added code above. In addition,if used named queue, every malicious client who know the queue name, can subscribe the message from the queue and make trouble for the system.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. Now lets assume you have a proper set up of `Erlang Rabbitmq client`. Using the users guide **[here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/erlang-client-user-guide.html)**.
**1. Generic RABBITMQ connector**

```
-module(rabbit_utils).
-compile(export_all).
-define(RABBIT_SERVER,"localhost").
-define(RABBIT_PORT,9001).

-record(pipe,{connection,channel}).

create_pipe()->    
    try amqp_connection:start(#amqp_params_network{host = ?RABBIT_SERVER,
                                                   port = RABBIT_PORT}) of
        {ok, Connection} -> 
            try amqp_connection:open_channel(Connection) of
                {ok,Channel} -> 
                    #pipe{
                        connection = Connection,
                        channel = Channel
                     };
                _ -> amqp_connection:close(Connection),error
            catch
                _:_ -> amqp_connection:close(Connection),error
            end;
        _ -> error
    catch
        _:_ ->  error
    end.

close_pipe(Channel,Connection)->
    try amqp_channel:close(Channel) of _ -> ok catch _:_ -> ok end,
    try amqp_connection:close(Connection) of _ -> ok catch _:_ -> ok end,
    ok.
```

You will notice as we continue, that, i keep creating pipes and closing pipes. This is because, in a recent version of the `erlang rabbitmq client`, the connection and channel variables, are Erlang processes. Whenever something does not go as planned inside this library, those processes die at runtime. For this reason, i am trapping most code in `try ... catch ... end` code blocks. If you are working with `gen_servers` , then , make them `trap_exit = true`, then, link them to the RabbitMQ client processes (Connection and Channel). So, whenever, the connection is interrupted, the `Connection` process will die, trap this in your gen_server, then, attempt another connection, if it fails, perhaps you have many `RABBITMQ` servers you can `fail over` to. Concepts are deep here, but lets continue. 

**2. Exchange manager**
 This one ensures that the exchange exists on `RABBITMQ` server. The exchange must be a `binary`. I am assuming that we need durable exchanges and queues. One advantage of durable exchanges and queues is that you create them once, and even if RABBITMQ service is restarted, it boots with these exchanges and queues.

```
ensure_exchange_exists(Exchange)->
    case create_pipe() of
        error -> error;
        #pipe{connection = Connection,channel = Channel} ->             
            RandomQueue = list_to_binary(guid()),            
            #'queue.declare_ok'{} = amqp_channel:call(Channel,#'queue.declare'{queue = RandomQueue}),
            Binding = #'queue.bind'{queue = RandomQueue,exchange = Exchange,
                                    routing_key = <<"testing">>},
            try amqp_channel:call(Channel, Binding) of 
                #'queue.bind_ok'{} ->                         
                        Delete = #'queue.delete'{queue = RandomQueue},
                        #'queue.delete_ok'{} = amqp_channel:call(Channel, Delete),
                        close_pipe(Channel,Connection),
                        ok;
                _ ->                     
                    close_pipe(Channel,Connection),
                    create_exchange(Exchange,Server)
            catch 
                _R:_T ->                     
                    close_pipe(Channel,Connection),
                    create_exchange(Exchange,Server)
            end;
        _ -> error
    end.

create_exchange(Exchange)->
    case create_pipe() of
        error -> error;
        #pipe{connection = Connection,channel = Channel} -> 
            Exc = #'exchange.declare'{exchange = Exchange,durable = true},
            try amqp_channel:call(Channel,Exc) of
                #'exchange.declare_ok'{} -> ok;
                _ -> close_pipe(Channel,Connection),error
            catch
                _:_ -> close_pipe(Channel,Connection),error
            end
    end.

guid()->
    random:seed(now()),
    MD5 = erlang:md5(term_to_binary([random:uniform(7677771995517),{self(),time(),node(), now(), make_ref()}])),
    MD5List = lists:nthtail(2, binary_to_list(MD5)),
    F = fun(N) -> f("~2.16.0B", [N]) end,
    L = [F(N) || N <- MD5List],
    lists:flatten(L).

f(S)-> f(S,[]).
f(S,Args) -> lists:flatten(io_lib:format(S, Args)).
```

**3. Queue Manager**
 For large systems, we found that it is easier to work with one exchange (or a few exchanges) but have as many queues as the systems need to interact. Imagine, that in a cluster, each system has a Queue, in which other systems send messages when they need to ask something from that system. Also, when a system gets a request from another system, it replies that request by sending the answer into the Queue of that system. With a good message format Protocol, which enables system Identification, differentiates requests from replies, time stamping, system pinging, remote procedure call, e.t.c you end up with a message router within your cluster. In a recent project we came up with a Remote procedure protocol, using `JSON` as a message format. Systems can call methods and pass arguments to a remote system over the AMQP interface. I cannot go into the details here, but just know, that it was so `Genuis` that we now rely on it `100%`.
 Anyhow, we need first, to be sure that a Queue exists, then, if it does, to check whether it is bound to our exchange. lets go !!

```
ensure_queue(Queue,Exchange)->
    #pipe{connection = Connection,channel = Channel} = create_pipe(),
    Get = #'basic.get'{queue = Queue},
    Sure = try amqp_channel:call(Channel, Get) of
                #'basic.get_empty'{} -> queue_exists;

                {#'basic.get_ok'{}, _Content} -> queue_exists;
                _ -> queue_missing
            catch
                _EE:_EE2 -> queue_missing
            end,
    close_pipe(Channel,Connection),
    case Sure of
        queue_exists -> ensure_bound(Queue,Exchange);
        queue_missing -> create_queue_and_ensure_bound(Queue,Exchange)
    end.

ensure_bound(Queue,Exchange)->
    #pipe{connection = Connection,channel = Channel} = create_pipe(),
    B1 = #'queue.bind'{queue = Queue,exchange = Exchange,routing_key = Queue},
    try amqp_channel:call(Channel, B1) of
        #'queue.bind_ok'{} ->
            close_pipe(Channel,Connection),
            ok;
        _OtherErr -> error
    catch
        _ET:_EY -> error
    end.


create_queue_and_ensure_bound(Queue,Exchange)->
    #pipe{connection = Connection,channel = Channel} = create_pipe(),
    TheQ = #'queue.declare'{queue = Queue,durable = true},
    try amqp_channel:call(Channel,TheQ) of
        #'queue.declare_ok'{} -> 
            Binding = #'queue.bind'{queue = Queue,exchange = Exchange,routing_key = Queue},
            try amqp_channel:call(Channel, Binding) of
                #'queue.bind_ok'{} ->
                    close_pipe(Channel,Connection),
                    error;
                _Other2 ->
                    close_pipe(Channel,Connection),
                    error
            catch
                _ER11:_ER22 ->
                    close_pipe(Channel,Connection),
                    error
            end;
        _Other ->
            close_pipe(Channel,Connection),
            error
    catch
        _ER1:_ER2 ->
            close_pipe(Channel2,Connection2),
            error
    end.
```

With fault tolerance added to a concrete erlang application, making use of some of the above code, you will have a very tight cluster. RABBITMQ availablity is very high, especially if you use it while understanding what you are doing. Most problems occur due to the network. What will your application do, if it loses connectivity with Rabbitmq server ? Redundancy comes in here. You can have various `RABBITMQ` servers, which all your cluster nodes are aware of and you have all the same exchanges and queues installed on all RABBITMQ servers, such that if one server is lost, the others can be used to continue the services.

Comment: I think you have used rabbitmq for linking of your multi-systems. But I use it for my system and third party program. The other program can't be trusted, so I have to restrict its behaviour for not wasting server's resource.